# Using jQuery UI Dialog to create popup for YES/NO are you sure you what to Delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jQuery UI Dialog to create a popup to ask if "Are you sure you want to delete" I what it to go from the starting link then to the function to check if it is allowed to be deleted if it is then popup yes no question. Then if they say YES send the script to the delete script or if they say NO send them back to the start page.

The script I have now does not open the dialog box automatically and I thought I understood the direction to autopen but it,s not working. Also I need it to have two links one for YES and one for NO.

This is the starting link to delete the data

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE pid = '$pid'");
foreach($result as $key => $value) {



   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'; 
   echo  $value['name'];
   echo '</td>'; 
   echo '<td>'; 
   echo $value['contact'];
   echo '</td>'; 
   echo '<td>';  
   echo "<a href = prosscust.php?custid=" . $value['custid'] . "&pid=" . $pid . "&name=" . $value['name'] . "></a>";
   echo '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';

 }
```

prosscust.php

```
require("function.php");
$pid =  $_SESSION['profile']['id'];

checkcustomeruse($custid,$pid,$name);
```

This is the function it calls

```
$custid = $_GET['custid'];
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

function checkcustomeruse($custid,$pid,$name){
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from signings WHERE pid = ? AND custid = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $custid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
$number = $number_of_rows;
//echo $number;
//exit;
 if($number == 0)
 {


?>
  <div id="callConfirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
<?php  
 }
 else
 {

  $Message = 'You can not delete this customer because it has signings attached to it.';
       header("Location: viewallcustomer.php?Message=" . urlencode($Message));  
 }

}
```

This is the jquery script

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

is "callConfirm" the div you're trying to have be the dialog? if so, change your javascript to this and it should work. the selector you are using doesn't exist.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#callConfirm" ).dialog({
       autoOpen: true,
       resizable: false,
       height:140,
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
       "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried so many combination I just put the wrong info on hear. My main problem is after you select yes I need to direct the link to go to the script to delete the data and a link if they say no to take them back to the page they started on. So how do you create a link in the script

Comment: well, instead of using a link, don't you think it would make more sense to make an ajax call to delete it so you won't be shifting the user all over the place?

Comment: Will write now the popup is on the prosscust.php and when I select yes or no I just have a blank page. But if the ajax call would get me to the delete it would return them to the page where they started with out them knowing. I would rather have the popup open in front of the page they start on but the delete link has to run threw a function to make sure it qualifies to be deleted

Comment: if you want to accomplish that, just pop up the dialog, bind the ok button to the ajax call, then when you're done, just close the dialog and remove the row from the display table that you just deleted. that will accomplish everything you want without ever having to refresh the page.

Comment: So are you saying using ajax I can call the function that will check the record to make sure they will be allowed to delete the record and if so ask them are they sure they want to do this if they say yes delete the record. And all this without leaving the page

Comment: yes, that's one of the great things about ajax. no postbacks. you could do all of the logic in the ajax call, if they have permission, delete the record, if not, throw an error.

Comment: OK I am going to have to rewrite the whole thing to do this. I do not know if I have the jquery skills to do this still learning and just started with jquery. Maybe I can find somebody that can do that for me. Thanks alot